# django s3 storages does not recognise the bucket name

Tags: django, boto, boto3

I am using [django-s3-storage==0.11.2](https://github.com/etianen/django-s3-storage) and [boto3==1.4.4](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). These are in the settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_cdn')

AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME = "my-bucket-name"
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'test_id_x'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'test_id_x+test_id_x'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "django_s3_storage.storage.S3Storage"
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "django_s3_storage.storage.StaticS3Storage"
AWS_S3_ADDRESSING_STYLE = "auto"
AWS_S3_BUCKET_AUTH_STATIC = False
AWS_S3_MAX_AGE_SECONDS_STATIC =  60 * 60 * 24 * 365  # 1 year.
AWS_S3_BUCKET_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_MAX_AGE_SECONDS = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365  # 1 year.
```

I have also ran these command:

```
manage.py s3_sync_meta django.core.files.storage.default_storage
```

But when I run `collectstatic` or this command

```
manage.py s3_sync_meta django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.staticfiles_storage
```

I get this error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid bucket name "": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$"
```

I have already created the bucket, and the bucket name is correct. Because this works and does not gives any error:

```
s3.meta.client.head_bucket(Bucket='my-bucket-name')
```

I don't know what am I missing here? Could you help me out please.

Comment: in the INSTALLED_APPS section in settings.py did you added __django_s3_storage__ ?

Comment: @tom Yes, I have added it to the installed apps in settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, it looks confusing for me too.

Below are my observations -

1 . Bucket name pattern

```
    Bucket name should not have '/' in them  .
     It would be good if you can update the AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME from 
     "my-bucket-name" to the pattern which actually resembles with your 
     bucket name.
  
  Source: https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/680
```

2 . In the [Django S3 Storage Documentation](https://github.com/etianen/django-s3-storage#migration-from-django-storages-non-redux) , it says

```
  If your are updating a project that used django-storages 
  just for S3 file storage, migration is trivial.

  Follow the installation instructions, replacing 'storages' in INSTALLED_APPS. 
  Be sure to scrutinize the rest of your settings file for changes, 
  most notably AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME for AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME.
```

Can you please try to change **AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME_STATIC = bass-line-shop** in your settings.py ?

Let me know, if it helps!

Comment: My bucket name is `bass-line-shop`, which should resemble the regex pattern. And also, changing `AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME` doesn't help.

Comment: ok , try adding AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME_STATIC = bass-line-shop in your settings.py

Comment: Yes, AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME_STATIC helped.

Comment: Sure, sorry I forgot.